# JAXB Webservice migrating from Weblogic 10 to 12

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, weblogic

I have a running webservice (JAX-WS 2.2) on a Weblogic 10.3. Everything works fine. So there can't be the problem in the wsdl.

I try to migrate to WLS 12. But now I get erros while deplyoment.

What has changed from WLS 10 to WLS 12 which yould cause the problem?

Comment: Error message or stack trace would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JAXB implementation changed for WLS 12.

- In Oracle Weblogic WLS10 Glassfish JAXB RI Implementation is provided
- In Oracle Weblogic WLS12 the EclipseLink Implementaiotn MOXy is provided

You can force WLS12 using JAXB RI as described [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24964/data_types.htm#CIHBHDGI)

You need to override the following two properties in order to tell WLS12 to use JAXB RI:

- com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory=com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory
- javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory

The simplest way to do this, is to **add a databinding.override_1.0.0.0.jar to your classpath**

Or you could set them as java system properties, but as written in the oracle docs

*In certain situations, it can be difficult to propagate the system properties to an indirectly invoked Java instance, such as a client forked from an Ant task. In these situations, it is important to ensure that the environment you are using propagates the properties.*

Comment: Where can I find the databinding.override_1.0.0.0.jar file?

Comment: As you can read in the documentation *The following jar file is provided in the WebLogic Server distribution to simplify the task of overriding the default data binding configuration:* `modules/databinding.override_1.0.0.0.jar`

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day. This was exactly the problem I had!

Answer (score 0):

I am upgrading from 10.3.6 to 12.2.1.3 and seeing the same issue: Exception below. modules/databinding.override_1.0.0.0.jar is not part of the distribution but I found: Oracle/Middleware_Home12c/wlserver/modules/databinding.override.jar which I included in the calsspath but that did not fix the issue, still getting the same exception.

```
Feb 07, 2019 9:22:51 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext

SEVERE: Context initialization failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'basketService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/store-services.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public synchronized java.lang.Object org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create()] threw exception; nested exception is Exception [EclipseLink-25037] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.5.v20170607-b3d05bd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException

Exception Description: A cycle is detected in the object graph.  This will cause an infinite loop: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.schema.model.ComplexType@8e926ca -> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.schema.model.Element@3e83f11a -> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.schema.model.Sequence@745d452e -> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.schema.model.ComplexType@8e926ca

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
```

Comment: This should be added as a comment, not as an answer.